# JavaFX application runs in IDE, with .bat, but not when double-clicked

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, jar

I've written a pretty simple JavaFX application. It is a Minesweeper clone that works perfectly when ran from the IDE.

Additionally, when exported as a runnable jar, I can get it to run with a .bat file with the following commands:

```
start javaw -jar MySweeper.jar
```

or

```
java -jar MySweeper.jar
```

However, it doesn't do anything when I double-click the jar file alone. Why is this? How can I fix this?

There are no errors when running. So it doesn't look like I'm missing dependencies.

I've seen other people post questions that seem similar to this. But usually their issue arises from the fact that the javafx libraries to their jar, but I don't think this is the same issue since it runs with the .bat

[MySweeper Demo Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUSnI.png)

Comment: What happens if you use `java -jar MySweeper.jar` instead of `start javaw -jar MySweeper.jar`? Also, add `pause` at the end of the batch file.

Comment: @dan1st It seems to work just the same. The program runs and nothing else appears in the console